# ssh2shell - Password prompt issue

Tags: ssh

I am using [ssh2shell](https://github.com/cmp-202/ssh2shell) for an interactive session. Below are the steps that I following:

1. Run a command
2. It asks for username. I stream.write the username in the onCommandProcessing event.
3. It asks for password. I do the same as i did for username.
4. Now i am required to press <kbd>enter</kbd> again to see the normal prompt. This is how the device is configured.

Since i need to press enter again (while doing it manually), my ssh2shell script is hung and timeouts.

I sent `\n` twice while sending the password, but still the problem persists.

This is my code for onCommandProcessing which handles the interactive session:

```
onCommandProcessing: function( command, response, sshObj, stream ){
if (new RegExp(/username:/i).test(response) && sshObj.usersent!==true){
    console.log("Inside user");
    stream.write(username+"\n");
    sshObj.usersent=true;
}
if (new RegExp(/password:/i).test(response) && sshObj.passsent!==true){
    console.log("Inside password");
    stream.write(password+"\n"+"\n");
    sshObj.passsent=true;
}
```

}

In this code, I am sending \n twice while sending the password (stream.write(password+"\n"+"\n"). But not sure whether this is the correct method.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you should show the relevant code.

Comment: how were you sending `\n` twice? can you show the code?

Comment: Sorry about that. I edited my post to include the code.